# LUN Id and Target Id mismatch on vSphere Client and ESX 4.1

Tags: scsi, esx, vsphere

I am fairly new to SCSI and storage. I have few LUNs exposed from a array to the ESX host. When I run sg_map -x on ESX 4.1 I see the LUN Ids shown as 0 for all the LUNs.

[root@SRESX41 ~]# sg_map -x

/dev/sg0  4 0 0 **0**  0  /dev/sda

/dev/sg1  4 0 1 **0**  0  /dev/sdb

/dev/sg2  4 0 2 **0**  0  /dev/sdc

/dev/sg3  4 0 3 **0**  0  /dev/sdd

/dev/sg4  4 0 4 0  0  /dev/sde

/dev/sg5  4 0 5 0  0  /dev/sdf

/dev/sg6  4 0 6 0  0  /dev/sdg

/dev/sg7  4 0 7 0  0  /dev/sdh

/dev/sg8  4 0 8 0  0  /dev/sdi

/dev/sg9  4 0 9 0  0  /dev/sdj

/dev/sg10  4 0 10 0  0  /dev/sdk

/dev/sg11  4 0 11 0  0  /dev/sdl

/dev/sg12  4 0 12 0  0  /dev/sdm

/dev/sg13  4 0 13 0  0  /dev/sdn

/dev/sg14  4 0 14 0  0  /dev/sdo

/dev/sg15  4 0 15 0  0  /dev/sdp

/dev/sg16  4 0 16 0  0  /dev/sdq

/dev/sg17  0 0 0 0  0  /dev/sdr

/dev/sg18  4 0 17 **0**  0  /dev/sds

/dev/sg19  4 0 18 **0**  0  /dev/sdt

/dev/sg20  4 0 19 **0**  0  /dev/sdu

But for the same LUNs the LUN id is shown different on the vSphere Client. Please find the attached screenshot of vSphere Clients. Can anyone provide me any idea onto why is the mismatch?

Answer (score 0):

[image: ESX vSphere Client showing LUN ID and Target ID]

Attaching the missing image on behalf of arun_vj